# Humanoid Jump Down Animation to Ground

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have one animation it climb to the wall and after jump down.But now when my model jump down is stands on air. but i want jump down animation finish on ground.How can i do this ?
[image: Stand Air]

Comment: Might be adjust Character Controller Height of character in Inspector or check the wall and basement collider

Comment: I don't think this is an animation issue. It depends on how you let your character know it's grounded. Common approach is using raycasting. Another (not recommended) would be checking **OnCollisionStay()**.

Comment: i solved with matchtarget thanx